# Encore script tag and clouflare rocket loader attribute

Tags: symfony, cloudflare, webpack-encore

I'm working on a Symfony 6.1 project and I'd need to add a custom attribute to one of my script tag generated by Encore in Twig, BEFORE the "src" attribute.

Here is the twig code:

```
{{ encore_entry_script_tags('js/theme-toggle', attributes={
    'data-cfasync': 'false'
}) }}
```

The generated HTML is the following:

```
<script src="/build/js/theme-toggle.5533f58c.js" defer data-cfasync="false">
```

Is there a way to make it appear before the "src" tag instead of after?

I really need it to disable CloudFlare "Rocket Loader" on this specific script: https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168056-Understanding-Rocket-Loader

Otherwise Rocket Loader breaks the page, and I don't really want to disable it for the whole page either.

Comment: Add the javascript into the html manualy without `encore_entry_script_tags`?

Comment: It's not possible because it's built and I don't know to exact name after each time it's built

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `encore_entry_js_files()` twig function to get the list of JS files and add the HTML by hand.

```
{% for js_file in encore_entry_js_files('js/theme-toggle') %}
    <script defer data-cfasync="false" src="{{ js_file }}">
{% endfor %}
```

From the [`symfony/webpack-encore-bundle`](https://github.com/symfony/webpack-encore-bundle#usage) documentation:

> If you want more control, you can use the `encore_entry_js_files()` and `encore_entry_css_files()` methods to get the list of files needed, then loop and create the `script` and `link` tags manually.